# slime-repl clozurecl not responding

Tags: emacs, lisp, read-eval-print-loop, slime

My slime-repl simply stopped responding after I called the following code:

1. I`ve created prompt-read:

   ```
   (defun prompt-read (prompt)
    (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
    (force-output *query-io*)
    (read-line *query-io*))
   ```
2. then called:

   ```
   (or(parse-integer(prompt-read "Whatever" ) :junk-allowed t) 0)
   ```
3. it prompted me:

   Whatever:
4. I had inputted "h" and that was it, it stopped responding, I read it could be something like slime-repl waiting for inputs in multiple threads. But I`ve no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `... :junk-allowed T)` ?

Comment: You`re right. That is what i wrote in my code.